# Tomcat difference in windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, tomcat, header, lowercase

At first, sorry for my poor English, please understand me)
I wonder that there is some different behaviors of converting between tomcat for windows pc and Linux server.
I mean that requested header names from browser are converted to lower case in tomcat with my pc, but Linux server's tomcat does not with the same web page.

The server application checks a header name received fro browser to equal to a server's key which has been already converted to lower case as read from the configuration file.

SO, it does work well as both keys being matched(lower case) with windows pc, but Linux server does not (header received from browser being not converted to lower case).

Please someone explain why this is.

Thank you.

Local PC : windows7
Server : Red Hat Linux Enterprise Linux server(release 6.2)
Tomcat version(both) : 7.0.57

Answer (score 0):

As converting headers to lowercase is called a WONTFIX [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58464), I would think windows advantages on what the bug says `to simplify the lookup of headers`. Maybe linux is more efficient with their lookups and won't need that conversion, passing headers in a more transparent way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The one thing that I wondering is that the WONTFIX means that it would not be fixed in the future or already fixed in a certain version.

Comment: It means it's never getting fixed. Take a look at [this](https://en.opensuse.org/Bug_Status_WONTFIX)